# Get the file name on lambda Amazon Webservice trigger

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm making a trigger event on a lambda function with Amazon Webservice but I can't figure out how to get the filename.

The trigger event is when a new file is created on my s3.

I'm using python and I the called function is :

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
```

Does anyone know how to get the file name added ?

Answer (score 5):

Here are some important info you can get from the s3 event:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        size = record['s3']['object']['size']
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        if size > 0:
            # do your stuff here
```

So to get the file from s3 you should use `bucket` and `key`

Comment: Thanks dude but that not giving me the file name just added

Comment: there's no such a thing as filename in S3. You have the concepts of `bucket` and `keys`. The key is the closest to the filename, maybe that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate, so if I don't have the filename, how could I open it and read on it ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this in python lambda event

```
import urllib.parse

bucket = event["Records"][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event["Records"][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
```

key is the file name